# Can you set aliases for npm scripts inside package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

I have a project written in `Typescript`

**When developing Locally:**

`ts-node` is installed as a dev-dependency, The commands are

```
  to start: "ts-node src/index"
  to init: "ts-node bin/init"
  to init db: "ts-node bin/database-init"
  to migrate db: "ts-node bin/database-migrate"
  to add users: "ts-node bin/add-users"
```

**When Deployed:**

dev-dependencies are dropped, app is transpiled, the commands are

```
  to start: "node src/index"
  to init: "node bin/init"
  to init db: "node bin/database-init"
  to migrate db: "node bin/database-migrate"
  to add users: "node bin/add-users"
```

---

Thus I am forced to maintain this in my `package.json` which will keep growing

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "ts-node src/index",
  "start:js": "node src/index",
  "init": "ts-node bin/init",
  "init:js": "node bin/init",
  "db:init": "ts-node bin/db-init",
  "db:init:js": "node bin/db-init",
  "db:migrate": "ts-node bin/db-migrate",
  "db:migrate:js": "node bin/db-migrate",
  "add:users": "ts-node bin/add-users",
  "add:users:js": "node bin/add-users"
},
```

I would much rather have a single command that works in both

---

to do this I have set the following alias in the deployment server

```
alias ts-node=/usr/bin/node
```

as such all these now works for both..

```
 "scripts": {
  "start": "ts-node src/index",
  "init": "ts-node bin/init",
  "db:init": "ts-node bin/db-init",
  "db:migrate": "ts-node bin/db-migrate",
  "add:users": "ts-node bin/add-users",
}
```

But this is not a great solution and prevents me from deploying it anywhere else.. I prefer to set the name space for `right-node` to `ts-node || node` inside the `package.json` this way it would be portable..

I know that the namespace for all dependencies gets added when running `npm scripts`, So this does happen behind the scenes, but is there any built in functionality to do this manually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the best solution is to work with NODE_ENV but first, you need to install:

```
npm install if-env --save
```

and then in the script:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production ?? npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
"start:dev": "ts-node src/index",
"start:prod": "node src/index"
```

}

And on the server you need to set NODE_ENV to production

On Linux:

```
export NODE_ENV=production
```

And for production, I suggest using something like pm2 or foverer insted node to start an application

Comment: Hey sorry, it wasn't just one command, it was a bunch. Question edited to more properly reflect the problem

Comment: You can use this if statement in all your task but instead invoke new script just use command directly in if statement. In this way, you will have one script for production and development environment